# elasticsearch c#/.net client recommendation

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

Which elasticsearch c#/.net client do you recommend?

1 - Nest: https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/commits/master

2 - elasticsearch.net: https://github.com/medcl/ElasticSearch.Net/commits/master

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IMHO, I think both still need more work as they don't have complete coverage of the ElasticSearch REST API, percolate and complete Query DSLs being the most conspicuous missing.

Having used NEST I think that is more suitable if you want strongly typed results:-

```
QueryResponse<Jobtitle> queryResults = _client.Search<Jobtitle>(search);
```

where as ElasticSearch.Net you get back something like:-

```
var result = client.QueryDSL.Search(index, new string[] { "type" }, query, 0, 5);
foreach (var VARIABLE in result.GetHits().Hits)
{
Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.Fields["name"]);
}
```

Whilst both APIs are missing features, they are on github so you can fork and help fill in the missing features.

I chose in the end to generate my own simple client from the [thrift IDL](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/transport/thrift/elasticsearch.thrift)

Comment: Author of NEST here, i think NEST is slightly ahead feature wise but neither are prime time ready yet. I can only state NEST is still actively developed.

Comment: Thanks be sure to harass me on github if you find any issues, missing features, ideas or suggestions :)

Comment: Any updates on this please? Is NEST mature enough Now to be used in a real time .net application?

Comment: Pretty old thread but I wish to know the updates as well. Can you please enlighten us with news on both? thanks